# footer overlapping over the previous div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not familiar with frontend so having a bit difficulty in creating a layout in html, css3 and bootstrap 4. I've done a little aminaton thing in the background like this https://codepen.io/mohaiman/pen/MQqMyo and after it I'm trying to put another div i.e footer, but it's overlapping. I think it's an issue with positioning. Please see the image attached and suggest some valuable ideas

```
<div class="page-header image" data-parallax="true" style="background-image: url('./assets/eCommerce_service.png');">
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <br>
    <div class="container-home">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mx-auto col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                <div class="motto text-center">
                    <img src="assets/logo.png" class="d-block img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mx-auto col-md-8">
                <div class="motto text-center">
                    <h1 class="presentation-title presentation-font">WEBBNET DIGITAL</h1>
                    <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdjOF6IWFyQxQ-n1WKfUzpyrqYN2gU4iexFAsz6gqrADIioXA/viewform"
                        class="btn btn-round" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-play">
                        </i>Get free session</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="section section-about-us area">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 ml-auto mr-auto text-center">
                <h2 class="title"><strong>Kolkata's Most <span style="color:#de6b28">Trendiest</span> Agency</strong></h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7 mx-auto">
                <p>Webbnet Digital is the most creative and trendiest digital marketing agency of Kolkata. We offer some of the highest demanding motion
                     graphics logos, posters banners and all sorts of online promotion.
                    </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 ml-auto margin">
                <img src="assets/seo_home.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="circles">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I started with the Codepen that you shared.

Basically, you need to make the `.area` div relatively positioned, so that the items that are absolutely positioned will be relative to the container they're within instead of the entire page. For the pen, I was then able to update the height of the circles and drop a footer below it:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/nmoncur/pen/jOPWobz?editors=1100)